# Solidity Event logs into HTML Table using Javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, solidity, web3js

I have two solidity events

```
event Approved(
        address indexed from,
        bytes32 indexed _id,
        string status,
        uint timestamp
    );
event Rejected(
        address indexed from,
        bytes32 indexed _id,
        string status,
        uint timestamp
    );
```

and i'm calling this from javascript as

```
approve = contract.Approved({_id: searchElement},{fromBlock: 379000, toBlock: 'latest'});
reject= contract.Rejected({_id: searchElement},{fromBlock: 379000, toBlock: 'latest'});
```

and watching it like

```
approve.watch(function(error, result){
        if (!error)
            loadToTable(result);
        });

reject.watch(function(error, result){
        if (!error) 
            loadToTable(result);
        });
```

I have total of 3 separate contracts with same Events in each and I call them as above in JS.

Now, the **PROBLEM** is

1)How to load it into table as the methods doesn't wait for the JSON response to be fetched, it gives empty table as i have tried.

2) I need to get the JSON response --> get one value(index:value) from it --> do database operation -->then show it in table.

*database operation : get result value and search for same in DB and get the related column details and populate it into table.

3)event.allEvents() method is not working for me is it related to geth version ?

I use **GETH 1.4.11** and please don't suggest to upgrade.

*I tried dynamic table snippet which worked in populating data but could not modify data.*

*I tried ajax,promise but either i used it wrong or it didn't work for me.*

Thanks in advance